# Selection reset issue when scrolling a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have 15 rows in my table. When I select the first row and scroll to last row of the table, and come to back to the first row, my selection is reset. How can I fix this row selection reset issue when scrolling the table?

Answer (score 0):

How are you selecting the row? Because of the table-cell reuse mechanism, just setting the `selected` property on an individual cell usually won't work; calling `-selectRowsAtIndexPaths:animated:` on the table view itself is the correct way to set its selection.

Comment: i'm selecting the rows in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath, how to call this selectRowsAtIndexPaths function..